# php DataGrid Control

Tags: php, datagridview

I want to use a grid view control on my php page, But when i use the below code, it gives error that C_DataGrid is not included in the File. How can i include the DataGrid in page, I have downloaded php Lite Grid view also

```
$dg = new C_DataGrid($hostName, $userName, $password, $dbName);

$dg -> set_gridpath     ("include/");
$dg -> set_sql          ("SELECT * FROM Employees");
$dg -> set_sql_table    ("Employees");
$dg -> set_sql_key      ("EmployeeId");
$dg -> display()
```

Comment: Check if library file for C_DataGrid class is included in your file..

Comment: no, i have not included. How to include that.

Comment: Which datagrid you are using ? give me URL

Comment: http://phpgrid.com/example/      , This is php GridLite. from the site i mentioned above

Answer (score 6):

SERVER_ROOT, known as ABS_PATH, shows the absolute URL to the phpGrid library folder on the server. This value tells your script where to find phpGrid library on the web server.

- Did you included require_once("phpGrid/conf.php"); in your php page ?
- Did you follow all the steps from http://phpgrid.com/documentation/installation/ ?

Comment: yes i have followed the steps and include the above url in page, but still an error is coming, saying Unable to open stream

Comment: Warning: require_once(/var/www/html//phpGridx/phpGrid.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/dev01/maiarn/phpGrid_Lite/server/classes/cls_datagrid.php(1) : eval()'d code on line 1

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/var/www/html//phpGridx/phpGrid.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/dev01/maiarn/phpGrid_Lite/server/classes/cls_datagrid.php(1) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: it seems path are not set in your file.see all files are located in proper place and also check configuration for path. Its only problem.

Comment: The complete folder is present on my server, And i have configured conf.php for my settings. Still the same error. I dnt kno why

Comment: try to debug every line and see where some file inclusion is not right.

Answer (score 3):

You actually have a very old phpGrid because set_gridpath function is no longer exists in the newer version. Instead the it is set in conf.php as SERVER_ROOT now.

You need to redownload the phpGrid Lite from their site again.